# How to extract phone numbers (numbers only) in Python using Regex from various formats from different countries?

Tags: python

I have a list of different phone number formats from different countries like:

```
+1 999-888-7777
999-888-7777
(999)-888-7777
(999) 888-7777
(999) 888 7777
+444 111 222 3333
+99 1 88888888
0123456789
333-55555
+11111
999-888-7777 ex.7777
999.888.7777
```

and I would like to have my output return only the actual phone number and remove any kind of formatting, like

```
9998887777
9998887777
9998887777
9998887777
9998887777
1112223333
188888888
0123456789
33355555
11111
9998887777
9998887777
```

Can you help me with a Regex in python that can do this?

Comment: what's the point of stripping the country code??

Comment: something like this ? `''.join(re.findall(r'(\d+)', '+444 111 222 3333'))`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @lenik that is the use case that I'm dealing with. Unfortunately I'm unable to tell you why specifically as it is company proprietary feature.

Comment: @syfluqs I tried the code you provided but it retains the country code. I need to strip out the country code and only have numbers.

Comment: @Barry Lucky, the country codes in your provided sample numbers are all different lengths and differently formatted, like +1 999-888-7777 becomes 9998887777 but +11111 becomes 11111. you will either have to code on a case by case basis, which i would not suggest, or source the country code and phone number separate from the start itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all instances of digits in the string with `re.findall` and join the resultant list together

```py
''.join(re.findall(r'(\d+)', phone_number_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

re.sub would be useful here.

```
s = '''
+1 999-888-7777
999-888-7777
(999)-888-7777
(999) 888-7777
(999) 888 7777
+444 111 222 3333
+99 1 88888888
0123456789
333-55555
+11111
999-888-7777 ex.7777
999.888.7777
'''

print('\n'.join(re.sub('\D', '', x) for x in s.split('\n')))
```

Comment: thank you, this currently retains all the numbers, including extensions and country codes. I have a use case that I need to remove country codes and extensions and only retain phone numbers.